# How does a movie get animals to "like" a character?

Tags: film-techniques

Suppose there is a movie in which the heroine is liked a lot by animals (as a means of foreshadowing how lovable she is to people).

1. Would they use an actress or actor that is naturally well-liked by animals, or conversely use animals that happen to like this character?
2. Can animals be trained (e.g. through [Pavlovian conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning)) to like a particular actress, or conversely, can a human being be trained to make herself likable to animals?
3. Are there drugs, scents or other stimuli that can used to make an animal like a person?

Which of these methods (or others) are used to get animals to like a particular character?

Comment: Peanut butter :)

Comment: @GCCampbell: I think I know you from one or two other sites. You made a good start. Could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: Trained animals are quite normal this days like [this](http://www.hollywoodanimals.com/) and [this](http://www.a1animals.co.uk/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hollywood pays actual Animal Trainers to bring the animals on set. They are given specific cues to act a certain way. You can watch a lot of behind the scenes with the animals on youtube for a better explanation.

They even have websites for Producers to look at and see the animals and training.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I was hoping for a more detailed response. But your answer has the merit of being the first, and perhaps will "break the ground" for others.

Comment: @TomAu Why would other people want to answer a question which appears to have been answered to your satisfaction?